# Authentication concepts for Apps

Tags: android, database, google-app-engine, authentication

I don't know whether i am asking a stupid question here.

I am just starting to learn and program android applications.

I wondered :

- How is the mechanism of an application and its back-end server works?
- How to have a user login and only the contents related to that user is shown?

Which is something  like when we login a Facebook account, we will have access to our information only.

Had a looked at SQL server and Data store and it seems like the database is shared for everyone using the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports client apps, AppEngine supports server apps, communication between them is HTTP(S).

[Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) are libraries of client code generated from server projects.  Endpoints perform authentication by passing client credentials to the AppEngine server.  Client app developers use Endpoint libraries instead of developing networking software themselves.

One of the AppEngine services is the optional [Users Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/) to look up information related to the client credentials.  If a server app needs to implement access control, it can be programmed to accept or reject requests per request detail and per user.  The application author is responsible for implementing such security.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin. However, does it means that to limit the information a user can access, we would need to implement it at the server side? 
I don't know much about server side, What i know is there are somekind of database server like SQL/datastore out there to store the application data. However, it seems the control part shouldn't be on the database servers. Does it means that i need another server between the device and the database server? Thanks!

Comment: Yes Zeon, you need to implement access control yourself on the server side.  The Datastore is too low level to implement Access Control Lists.  What you may need to do is store permissions as metadata alongside the user data somehow.  You have to design as much of that as you need within your server application.

Comment: Thanks Martin, may i know what kind of server am i looking at? and is there any material to study and guide me on that? also, is it possible to be done using google app engine? thanks.